# "OSError: Error opening adapter" when using scapy sniff (Python)

Tags: python, scapy

I am trying to write a code in python that sniffing packets in my computer and printing those that are dns ones. but for some reason I keep getting this error.
[image]

this is my code:

```
from scapy.all import *
from scapy.layers.dns import DNS, DNSQR
from scapy.layers.inet import IP, UDP


def print_packets(pkg):
    if DNS in pkg:
        pkg.show()


def is_dns(pkg):
    if "DNS Resource Record" in pkg:
        return DNS
    return False


def main():
    packets = sniff(filter=is_dns, prn=print_packets)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

can someone tell me why it's happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

> why it's happening?

You appear to be encountering a permission error.

That is, the `sniff( ... )` call is quite standard,
and the subsequent request for `ETH_P_ALL` is what you want.
But you seem to lack permission to see such interfaces.

---

> how can I fix it?

Note that the intro / install docs always take care
to specify UID=0 root access, e.g. `$ sudo ./run_scapy`.
On your platform I'm not sure what exactly it takes
to convince the ether API that you're a legitimate admin.
Follow the [docs](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#windows):

> the latest version of Scapy supports Windows out-of-the-box.

> If really nothing seems to work, consider skipping the Windows version and using Scapy from a Linux Live CD ...

> You may not be able to capture WLAN traffic on Windows ....

---

If you believe a response is an answer to your question,
it is appropriate to [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).